# Extracting Table from CSV file using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to extract specific tables from a report using Python and compile the data as a single table. However, it seems that once it selects or finds the desired series of column names, it copies all the data underneath, including all the necessary data that is not readable to the machine. The output should be in a table format. I'm running it in Jupyter Notebook.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

# Function to extract relevant data from the CSV file
def extract_data_from_csv(file_path):
    data_start = False
    headers = []
    rows = []

    with open(file_path, newline='') as csvfile:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        
        for row in csv_reader:
            if not data_start:
                if row and row[0] == "SUBSCRIBER NAME":
                    headers = row
                    data_start = True
            elif data_start and row:
                if row[0].strip().upper() == "PRODUCT TOTAL":
                    break
                rows.append(row)

    return headers, rows

# Specify the path to your CSV file
csv_file_path = 'Testing/sample report.csv'

# Extract data
headers, rows = extract_data_from_csv(csv_file_path)

# Create a DataFrame using pandas
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=headers)

# Display the DataFrame as a table
display(df)

# Save the DataFrame to a new CSV file
output_csv_file_path = 'mark_table_1.csv'
df.to_csv(output_csv_file_path, index=False)
```

Please refer the google link for the files:
[Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12KncHDnMNxVuBs8G3zGWWrmaJZ1uGIMT?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

**I have not tested it**, but you can try changing the `extract_data_from_csv` with the below

```
# Function to extract relevant data from the CSV file
def extract_data_from_csv(file_path):
    data_start = False
    headers = []
    rows = []

    with open(file_path, newline='') as csvfile:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        
        for row in csv_reader:
            if not data_start:
                if row and row[0] == "SUBSCRIBER NAME":
                    headers = row
                    data_start = True
            elif data_start and row:
                if row[5].strip().upper() == "PRODUCT TOTAL": #changed row index to 5 
                    data_start = False #in place of break
                rows.append(row)

    return headers, rows
```

Where two changes made are:

1. Index change from `row[0].strip().upper() == "PRODUCT TOTAL"` to `row[5].strip().upper() == "PRODUCT TOTAL"`
2. Replaced `break` with `data_start = False` to temporarily halt row writing until a new "SUBSCRIBER NAME" table appears; **Note** that
   `headers` will be rewritten in the `if` statement, but that should not be an issue as they are always the same, you can also modify the function further to avoid this

Answer (score 1):

Might want to consider a custom generator function that loops over the file, starts capturing at a certain condition, then consumes and yields the rest, until another condition (or end of file) and breaks to continue looking for the first condition, (not massively dissimilar to what you've done), but eg:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

def extract(filename):
    with open(filename) as fin:
        csvin = csv.reader(fin)
        for row in csvin:
            if row and row[0] == 'SUBSCRIBER NAME':
                for subrow in csvin:
                    if subrow and subrow[0]: # change me perhaps?
                        yield dict(zip(row, subrow))
                    else:
                        break
```

Then get your DataFrame by:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(extract('your_file_name'))
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your huge help. I've got it!. 
I want to paste the whole code but it seems it's too long. haha.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I've got it.

Sharing the whole code for future reference.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

# Function to extract relevant data from the CSV file
def extract_data_from_csv(file_path):
    headers = None
    rows = []

    with open(file_path, newline='') as fin:
        csvin = csv.reader(fin)
        for row in csvin:
            if row and row[0] == 'SUBSCRIBER NAME':
                headers = row
                for subrow in csvin:
                    if subrow and subrow[0].strip().upper() == 'PRODUCT TOTAL':
                        break
                    elif subrow and subrow[0]:
                        rows.append(subrow)
                    else:
                        break

    return headers, rows

# Specify the path to your CSV file
csv_file_path = 'Testing/0976_Bills_Payment_Abstract_of_Collection_11142023_115828.csv'

# Extract data using the new extract function
headers, rows = extract_data_from_csv(csv_file_path)

# Create a DataFrame using pandas
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=headers)

# Display the DataFrame as a table
display(df)

# Save the DataFrame to a new CSV file
output_csv_file_path = 'mark_table_2.csv'
df.to_csv(output_csv_file_path, index=False)
```